# Possible to re-order randomized/non-sequential ActiveRecord ID values from test data in rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

I created an initial data set for an app using test data, which used randomized ActiveRecord IDs.

Is there a cookbook recipe for a good clean rails way to condense and serialize these starting with 0? Maybe pure SQL would be faster than ActiveRecord?

I will also have to correct association ids. Rails 3.2.11, postgresql

Comment: Why does it matter what the `id`s are? They're unique and that's sufficient, no?

Comment: I will run out of ids a lot sooner since it's incrementing from the highest one in the test data.

Comment: But how big is the largest `id` you used? A PostgreSQL `serial` column is a 32bit signed integer and that's pretty big, a `bigserial` is 64bit and that's crazy-big for almost anything you're going to be doing.

Comment: I should check for the largest value to be sure, but I assumed that the test data had a random spread so it would well cover the range. But I also am curious if there is a way to do this regardless of whether I need to this in this case.

Comment: There is a way but it isn't much fun. You'd probably use `generate_series` or the `row_number` window function to build an old->new `id` mapping table in the database, then do an UPDATE with a JOIN or subquery to update the PK values and more UPDATEs to fix the FKs. If your largest value is only ~1e6 or so then I don't think I'd bother.